# Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, php

I've a query in my php script

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT State_Id FROM state_master WHERE State_Name='$statename'") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $row['State_Id'];
```

Which returns `23Unknown column 'State_Name' in 'where clause'` where 23 is the correct state ID. What I'm doing wrong?

Is there any way to avoid the error and just to return the value?

I'm new in this so I hope someone will point out my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `DESC state_master;`. This will show you all the columns in that table.

Fine the correct column name for the state name. Evidently, from the error, it is not `State_name`. Then, use that correct column name in the SQL Statement.

If `State_Name` is the actual column name, then try lowercase on all column names

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT state_Id FROM state_master WHERE state_name='$statename'") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $row['state_Id'];
```

Give it a Try !!!